# Need to check all my variables for an ampersand, I put variables in a list and check using a for loop, but Python only changes value inside list

Tags: python, list

I've got the following code, but unfortunately it only changes the value inside the list. Is there any way I can change the value outside the list, so it can be used later in the script?

```
street_number = "100 & 102"
street_name = "Fake Street"
suburb = "Faketown"

allvariables = [street_number, street_name, suburb]

ampersand = "&"
ampersand_escape = "&amp;"

for i, item in enumerate(allvariables):
    if isinstance(item, str):
        if ampersand in item:
            allvariables[i] = item.replace(ampersand,ampersand_escape)

print(allvariables) # -> ['100 &amp; 102', 'Fake Street', 'Faketown']
print(street_number) # -> 100 & 102
```

The only alternative I can imagine is checking each variable individually, but I've got a LOT of variables that need to be checked so it would take forever:

```
if ampersand in street_number:
    street_number.replace(ampersand,ampersand_escape)

if ampersand in street_name:
    street_name.replace(ampersand,ampersand_escape)

if ampersand in suburb:
    suburb.replace(ampersand,ampersand_escape)
```

But that seems extremely time consuming. Thank you in advance for your help!

***P.S. just in case - I need to do a few more checks besides the ampersands***

Comment: It changes the value inside the list because you assign the changed value to the list at `allvariables[i] = item.replace(ampersand,ampersand_escape)`. If you want to change the value of `street_number` only then it should be `street_number = item.replace(ampersand,ampersand_escape)`.

Comment: Note that you don't actually need those `if ampersand in X:` checks - `.replace()` will work just fine even if there are zero replacements to be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each variable in python (for instance, `street_number`) is just a reference to something. In this case, `street_number` is a reference to a string, namely "100 & 102".

When you write `allvariables = [street_number, street_name, suburb]`, you are simply creating a list with elements that have been initialized by the variables. So in your list, position 0 contains a string which was copied from `street_number` and has the same value "100 & 102", but there is no ongoing linkage to the variable `street_number`.

So if you update `allvariables[0]` to be '100 & 102', this will have no effect on the value referenced by the variable `street_number`.

One way to get the result I think you want would be this:

```py
street_number = "100 & 102"
street_name = "Fake Street"
suburb = "Faketown"

allvariableNames = ['street_number', 'street_name', 'suburb']

ampersand = "&"
ampersand_escape = "&amp;"

ampIndices = [i for i, item in enumerate(allvariableNames) if isinstance(eval(item), str) and ampersand in eval(item)]
for i in ampIndices:
    exec(f'{allvariableNames[i]} = {allvariableNames[i]}.replace(ampersand, ampersand_escape)')
print(', '.join(f"'{eval(item)}'" for item in allvariableNames)) # -> ['100 &amp; 102', 'Fake Street', 'Faketown']
print(street_number)
```

Output:

```
'100 &amp; 102', 'Fake Street', 'Faketown'
100 &amp; 102
```

Explanation:

- instead of initializing a list using the variables you have in mind, initialize a list with the names of these variables as strings
- build a list of the indices into the variable name list for the value of the variable (obtained using the `eval()` function) contains the search pattern
- use `exec()` to execute a python statement that uses the string name of the variable to update the variable's value by replacing the search pattern with the new string `&amp`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like all your variables are related to each other, so using a dictionary to store the variables might be a good idea. Like a list, you can look over it, but unlike a list, you can give its members names. Here's some example code:

```py
address = {
    "street_number": "100 & 102",
    "street_name": "Fake Street",
    "suburb": "Faketown",
}

ampersand = "&"
ampersand_escape = "&amp;"

for (item, value) in address.items():
    if isinstance(value, str):
        if ampersand in value:
            address[item] = value.replace(ampersand,ampersand_escape)
print(address)
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings in Python are immutable which means that once created they cannot be changed. Only a new string can be created. So what you want to do is to store the newly created string back in the same variable.
for example

```
s = "hello"
s.upper() #does not change s.. only creates a new string and discards it
s = s.upper() # creates the new string but then overrides the value of s
```

Also, adding strings to the list means any manipulation you do won't affect the original string.